# Запуск файля .py через консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

В консоле пытаюсь запустить файл .py такой командой

```
/home/argus/python_hsi/bin/python3 /home/argus/hsi_app/hsi_qt_app/app.py
```

То есть путь к питону и путь к файлу
В итоге запускается сам питон, а не файл. Вторую часть команды, где прописан файл,будто он не видит.
Запускаю в ubuntu

Comment: Попробуйте `/home/argus/python_hsi/bin/python3 "/home/argus/hsi_app/hsi_qt_app/app.py"`

Comment: @MichaelTetelev Пробелов и других особых символов тут вроде нет, поэтому кавычки не должны влиять

Comment: А каково содержимое `app.py`? Может скрипт отрабатывает, но вы этого не замечаете? Не читает ли он каких-то данных из текущего каталога? Учтите, что при таком запуске текущий каталог будет вовсе не тот, в котором расположен скрипт.

Comment: Кавычки не помогли(
В содержимом app.py код на более чем 1000 строк. Это один из файлов приложения.
Такой момент: Две Убунты и одна Кубунту. Вот как раз на Кубунту эта херня происходит. На Убунту норм